# Anonymous variables, passing by reference, initializer lists

Tags: c++, initialization, pass-by-reference, anonymous-types

So I'm just getting caught up in some nuisances of C++. Specifically, passing anonymous variables by reference for use in an initializer list for a class in C++. Consider the following code;

```
class A {
public:
  int x;

  A(int x=0) : x(x) {
    std::cout <<"A: creatred\n";
  }

  ~A() {
    std::cout << "A: destroyed\n";
  }
};

class B {
public:
  A a;

  B(const A& in) : a(in) {
    std::cout <<"B: creatred\n";
  }

  ~B() {
    std::cout << "B: destroyed\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  B b(A(0));
  std::cout << "END\n";
  return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
A: creatred
B: creatred
A: destroyed
END
B: destroyed
A: destroyed
```

I count 2 creations and 3 destructions. What's going on? Way I see it, I'm using an anonymous variable `A(0)` as input when creating `b`. Not sure what the order of things are now. A reference to the anonymous variable is created and used to copy (the copy constructor will be called in the initializer list, yes?) the member variable `a`. When is the anonymous variable destroyed? And in general, why am I seeing 2 constructors called and 3 destructors. Thanks.

Comment: They're affectionately called temporary variables in c++.

Comment: instead of anonymous variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't override `A`'s copy constructor to print a message...

Specifically, `a(in)` invokes it.

Answer (score 3):

The missing constructor would be the copy constructor for A.

You copy construct A in the below line.

```
B(const A& in) : a(in)
```

---

```
A: destroyed
END
```

This is the temporary being destroyed, it is destroyed at the end of the line

```
B b(A(0));
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. still trying to wrap my head around it all